# Get List of Printer Drivers from list of Computers PowerShell

Tags: powershell, printing

I've tried a variety of iterations of this and gotten a range of errors. I'm trying to get a a list of installed drivers off from a list of computers. None of the ways I've tried in PowerShell have piped the information into a csv. Here's the current iteration of the script.

```
#Load Active Directory 
Import-Module activedirectory
#Load list of computers
$results = @()
$Computer = Get-Content -path 'C:\ScriptResources\computers.txt'

#Check each computer in the list 
foreach($ComputerName in $Computer)
    {
    $results += Get-ADComputer -Filter " Name -Like '*$ComputerName*' " | Get-PrinterDriver; Start-Sleep -milliseconds 500 
    } 

#Export to CSV file
$results | export-csv 'C:\ScriptResults\InstalledPrinters.csv'
```

I've also used it with just the Get-Printer command and got the following error.

```
Get-Printer : No MSFT_Printer objects found with property 'Name' equal to 'Redacted'.  Verify the value of the
property and retry.
```

Depending what I've fed the $Computer file I'll get different errors. I've also gotten the RPC server is unavailable and Error Spooler Service Not Running. I have domain wide privileges and I checked the print spooler service and it is running.

The reason I think this is odd is that I have .bat tool that I use that gets printer info from a singular host and I don't run into any issues. The reason I'm trying to put this in PowerShell is because 1) I want to do the whole domain and 2) PowerShell formats its outputs in a more useable fashion.

```
wmic /node:%ComputerIP% path win32_printer get deviceid, drivername, portname
```

Additionally, I've also tried the following in the $results function of the script

```
$results += Get-WmiObject -class Win32_printer -ComputerName name, systemName, shareName
```

This didn't give errors. What it did instead is that for each computer in the list of computers it checked the computer I was running the script from for its printers and output on each line which printers were installed on my computer.

I'm at a loss and any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try changing `$results += Get-WmiObject -class Win32_printer -ComputerName name, systemName, shareName` to `$results += Get-WmiObject -class Win32_printer -ComputerName $Computer | Select name, systemName, shareName`

Comment: Another thing, 
In `$results += Get-ADComputer -Filter " Name -Like '*$ComputerName*' " | Get-PrinterDriver`, why are you using `Get-ADComputer` to filter the computer names. `Get-PrinterDriver` itself has a `-ComputerName` parameter, which you can use instead!

Comment: I believe I went with Get-ADComputer when I continued to get a different error using the -ComputerName paramenter. 

I have a separate script I wrote that actually needed ADComputer information and it works so I figured I'd just test it out to see if I could get somewhere. 

I'll try your suggestions over the weekend and let you know how it goes. 

If I can reproduce the error code I encountered, I'll post it here. 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Here's the problem I'm having when I use

`$results += Get-WmiObject -class Win32_printer -ComputerName  $Computer | Select name, systemName, shareName`

I get the error: 

`Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from 
HRESULT: 0x800706BA)`

Comment: I've already check to make sure that both my Remote Procedure Call and Windows Management Instrumentation services are running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so this is closed out. Vivek's answer ended up working.

`$results += Get-WmiObject -class Win32_printer -ComputerName $Computer | Select name, systemName, shareName`

The RPC issue I was getting was that the list of computers were all turned off for some reason (remote site + different time zone + doing the testing during second shift). Normally, everything remains on though. So that was just an anomaly.

Thanks for the help!